# Gauge R&R analysis - Preicision of a system

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, reproducible-research, repeatability, gauge

I never attempted to do a GR&R analysis before so I'm sharing an overview of what I would like to attempt to do and hopefully I would get some insight/advice/reference on which approach I should use.

I have a system, containing 280 parts. One operator measures 52 points (current, voltage, power or whatever) and repeat this measurement 10 times for each part.
I would like to know how accurate/precise is my system for each part (or for all parts), could anyone give me an advice or a reference on which approach in GR&R I could use to extract the precision of the system?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is write a clear step-by-step protocol for the operators. This will allow you to identify potential room for improvement in case you observe significant variance among operators and/or parts. Add to that the objective in terms of 'how much variation is acceptable and that was is not'. Variance expressed in percentages and/or in F- value gives a clear summary of how much variation there is. Together with a p-value, you could separate methods you consider acceptable and those that are not. One of the most important aspects is to decide how much variation is acceptable and not.

Perhaps this link could be of use: [https://quality-one.com/grr](https://quality-one.com/grr/)
For actually doing the statistics I would suggest a program that is open-source. R and R-studio are great, but a simple spreadsheet could work fine for a few operators.